# Python os.popen requires an integer?

Tags: python

I'm running python 2.7.3 and doing some basic stuff involving the os module.

```
import os

def main():
    f= os.popen('cat  > out', 'w',1)
    os.write(f, 'hello pipe')
    os.close(f)

main()
```

Based on examples I've seen I would expect the code to work, but the interpreter gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "./test.py", line 8, in main
    os.write(f, 'hello pipe')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Okay, off to the documentation. The help page says:

```
write(...)
    write(fd, string) -> byteswritten

    Write a string to a file descriptor.
```

fd seems to stand for file descriptor. Presumably this is what you get when you do something like:

```
file = open('test.py')
```

No surprise, online documentation says the exact same thing.
What's going on here?

Comment: Why not just use `subprocess`?

Comment: Because I want to get data from a website, and as the data comes in pipe it to another process. Is there a better way to do this with subprocess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a "file descriptor" is an integer, not the `file` object. To go from a `file` object to a file descroptor, call `file.fileno()`. To wit:

```
>>> f = open("tmp.txt", "w")
>>> help(f.fileno)
Help on built-in function fileno:

fileno(...)
    fileno() -> integer "file descriptor".

    This is needed for lower-level file interfaces, such os.read().

>>> f.fileno()
4
```

Instead of using that, though, you probably just want to do the following, unless you really need to use the low-level functions for some reason:

```
f = os.popen('cat  > out', 'w',1)
f.write('hello pipe')
f.close()
```

Comment: So it worked, but why does python use an integer as a file descriptor? Why not just the file object? Is the file descriptor some sort of pointer?

Comment: @Muricula: the file descriptor is to interface with the low-level C libraries. it's what they use to do file i/o. python wraps this nicely with the file object but if you're using the low-level libraries then you gotta give em what they know